# The website does not remove elements, despite the prescribed code

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mysql-python

I have a code that can add, change or delete data. Adding and changing works well, but deleting doesn't work. There is simply no response to pressing the button. What is the reason?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm, EditForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class DeletePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    sucсess_url=reverse_lazy('home')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView, AddPostView, UpdatePostView, DeletePostView
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('article/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='update_post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/remove', DeletePostView.as_view(), name='delete_post'),
]
```

delete_post.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>DELETE</title>
  </head>
<h3>Delete: {{post.title}}</h3>
<div class="form-group">
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <button class="btn btn-secondary">Delete</button>
   </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Really *no* response? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to track down the problem more precisely. For example, when you look at the page source in the browser, does it look right? What if you open the developer console in the browser before clicking the button - can you verify if a request is being sent to the server? On the server side, can you see whether the expected route handler is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this helper method as an action on your form element
and type of the button as submit.

`action="{% url 'delete_post' Post.id %}"`

Like this:

```py
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <title>DELETE</title>
  </head>
<h3>Delete: {{post.title}}</h3>
<div class="form-group">
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_post' Post.id %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Delete</button>
   </form>
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT:

Just spotted that you use the UpdateView for your DeleteView.

Edit it to:

```py
class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    sucсess_url=reverse_lazy('home')
```

Comment: error: Reverse for 'delete_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/remove\\Z']